# first flight starmac-ros-pkg and gazebo simulation

Tags: gazebo, simulation, rviz, simulator-gazebo, pelican

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

i'm following the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/starmac-ros-pkg/Tutorials/First%20Flight) for the first flight using starmac-ros-pkg.

What can i do for launch the simulation and control the quadrotor from keyboard?

after that, i need also to simulate the quadrotor on Gazebo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12079/first-flight-starmac-ros-pkg-and-gazebo-simulation/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2011-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Maurizio,

You need active the "soft_yoystick" in the argument of the sim.launch, so do:

roslaunch simulated_quadrotor sim.launch dummy_joystick:=false soft_joystick:=true
(or change de defaults values)

CAUTION: You need the version 0.1.0 of the starmac pakage, so you don't make "$ hg update -r version-0.0.1" in the installation. After that, you'll be able see a joystick in your monitor. I hope that works!!

I think that the starmac package doesn't work directly in Gazebo. But I am not sure, sorry.

---

Originally posted by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) with karma: 90 on 2011-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on 2011-11-24**:
thanks Rikki, where can i find some documentation about this package? Can you suggest me something else for moving a quadrotor on Gazebo?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI!

1. Look at this line:

*"line 10, in  from PySide.QtCore import QThread ImportError: No module named PySide.QtCore process"*

You need to install the Pyside packages (qtcore and gui). I think that you can find that in Synaptic searching "pyside".

2. DO: roslaunch simulated_quadrotor sim.launch dummy_joystick:=false soft_joystick:=true **show_plots:=false** (sorry, I forgot that)
3. And don't worry for this error: [1322215686.212243982]: XML Document "/home/mauro/ros_workspace/starmac-ros-pkg/starmac_common/starmac_tools/nodelets.xml" had no Root Element. This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.

I don't know why fail this node, however the programe run well.

4. For Gazebo you need create a URDF robot, but I don't know if you can modificate the starmac package for that, sorry.

SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH AND GOOD LUCK   :)

---

Originally posted by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) with karma: 90 on 2011-11-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1